# ClickOnce CheckForUpdate() returns null after a while

Tags: c#, multithreading, clickonce, updates

I have a problem with a ClickOnce application, when I call `CheckForUpdate()` for a while it works, and I the restart system works perfectly. After about one hour it starts crashing. I'm running this on a seperate thread and the ClickOnce application is on our local network.

**The error code:**

> System.Deployment.Application.DeploymentException: An application for this deployment is already installed with a different application identity. at System.Deployment.Application.SubscriptionStore.CheckAndReferenceApplication(SubscriptionState subState, DefinitionAppId appId, Int64 transactionId)
>      at System.Deployment.Application.DeploymentManager.BindCore(Boolean blocking, TempFile& tempDeploy, TempDirectory& tempAppDir, FileStream& refTransaction, String& productName)
>      at System.Deployment.Application.DeploymentManager.Bind()
>      at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationDeployment.CheckForDetailedUpdate(Boolean persistUpdateCheckResult)
>      at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationDeployment.CheckForUpdate()

**Here is the method:**

```
private void RestartUpdate()
{
    bool running = true;
    while (running)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(5000);
        try
        {
            if (!RESTARTING)
            {
                if (ApplicationDeployment.IsNetworkDeployed)
                {
                    ApplicationDeployment updateCheck = ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment;
                    bool newUpdate = updateCheck.CheckForUpdate(); **<---- Problem**
                    if (newUpdate == true)
                    {
                        RESTARTING = true;
                        updateCheck.UpdateCompleted +=
                        new AsyncCompletedEventHandler(
                        Deployment_UpdateCompleted);
                        updateCheck.UpdateAsync();                               
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            SendErrorMessageToServer(e.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Do you have any clue why this is happening?

EDIT:

Found an answer from James Miles who seems to bypass the click-once deployment API entirely when checking for updates:

```
//Used to use the Clickonce API but we've uncovered a pretty serious bug which results in a COMException and the loss of ability
//to check for updates. So until this is fixed, we're resorting to a very lo-fi way of checking for an update.
var manifestFile = new WebClient().DownloadString(updateLocation);
var xdoc = XDocument.Parse(manifestFile);
XNamespace nsSys = "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1";
var version = new Version(xdoc.Descendants(nsSys + "assemblyIdentity").First().Attribute("version").Value);
```

Comment: Are crashes begun after the update of the application? If so, you must alter the application version number in `AssemblyInfo`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went for the solution that bypasses the `OneClick` API.

```
string manifestFile = new WebClient().DownloadString(@"\\*\*.application");
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Parse(manifestFile);
XNamespace nsSys = "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1";
Version versionNew = new Version(xdoc.Descendants(nsSys + "assemblyIdentity").First().Attribute("version").Value);
int result = applicationDeplayment.CurrentVersion.CompareTo(versionNew);
if (result < 0)
{
   applicationDeplayment.UpdateAsync();
}
```